# Assembly 8086 - How to insert string buffer into another string buffer?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm making a program, which instead of "1bc" writes "ONEbc". However, I'm struggling to insert one string inside another. I managed to do that the program changes each char, but I need to insert a whole string, not symbol by symbol, while also my program doesn't print the rest of the text (just "ONE"). This is the segment which changes 1 into ONE.

```
.DATA
        one db "ONE" ; I want to include this into my code somehow

**************************************************

    MOV cx, ax
    MOV si, offset firstBuf ; (firstBuf db "1bc")
    MOV di, offset newBuf ; (should be "ONEbc" after this)
  work:
    MOV dl, [si]
    CMP dl, '1'
    JNE continue  
        ADD ax, 3     
    MOV cx, ax
    MOV [di], 'O'
    INC si
    INC di
    MOV [di], 'N'
    INC si
    INC di
    MOV [di], 'E'   
    JMP next
  continue: 
    MOV [di], dl   
  next:
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP    work
```

As you can see, I have tried putting the string symbol by symbol, but I think there's a better way to do that. I'm a beginner and I'm using emu8086, if that helps.

Comment: It's not an entirely trivial change, but basically you would load the offset of `one` into `bx`, then load characters from that as you do for `firstbuf` and store them in `newBuf` instead of storing the literals that you do now. You would need to keep track of the length of the string to insert, either by having an explicit length, or by using a terminator, like `$`. --- Incidentally, should you be incrementing `si` when writing out `O` `N` `E` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output didn't show "bc" because of the 2 additional increments on the SI register! And changing CX in the middle of the loop will cause reading past the source string, so don't do that either.

```
    MOV cx, ax       ; Length of the input string
  work:
    MOV dl, [si]
    INC si
    CMP dl, '1'
    JNE continue  
    ADD ax, 2        ; New length of the output string we're building
    MOV [di], 'O'
    INC di
    MOV [di], 'N'
    INC di
    MOV dl, 'E'   
  continue: 
    MOV [di], dl
    INC di
    LOOP    work
```

> I have tried putting the string symbol by symbol, but I think there's a better way to do that.

You can output 2 characters together:

```
    MOV cx, ax       ; Length of the input string
  work:
    MOV dl, [si]
    INC si
    CMP dl, '1'
    JNE continue  
    ADD ax, 2        ; New length of the output string we're building
    MOV word [di], 'ON'
    ADD di, 2
    MOV dl, 'E'   
  continue: 
    MOV [di], dl
    INC di
    LOOP    work
```

You could also retrieve the "ONE" string from somewhere else. Especially interesting if the text to insert is somewhat longer.

```
    MOV cx, ax       ; Length of the input string
  work:
    MOV dl, [si]
    INC si
    CMP dl, '1'
    JNE continue  
    mov bx, OFFSET one
    mov bp, 2
    add ax, bp        ; New length of the output string we're building
nestedLoop:
    mov dl, [bx]
    inc bx
    mov [di], dl
    inc di
    dec bp
    jnz nestedLoop
    mov dl, [bx]
  continue: 
    MOV [di], dl
    INC di
    LOOP    work
```